# issue with extension library value picker in xpages (extlib.SampleDataUtil)

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I am having issue with value picker of extension library. When i use java file exitlib/pickers/SimplePicker.java system shows following errors.

i)  SampleDataUtil cannot be resolved
ii) The import exitlib.SampleDataUtil cannot be resolved

I have gone through a thread on internet that in application properties advanced tab i have to check following 2 options

com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library 
com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.library

but these options are not available to me. Can anybody guide me where I am having issue in implementing extension library.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like things are possibly not installed correctly....

Try `tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlibx` on the server console to see if it is resolved.

If not, the installation hasn't worked correctly on the server.

Another option is you haven't installed in designer?

The below is a good reference for installing on both server and client

http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/extension-lib

Comment: thanks for your response. Sample extension library database is working perfectly but when i use same in my application it don't works. I have tried your command it runs perfectly fine.